# Can I export the motion data of a rigid body?

Tags: export, rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body simulation in Blender 2.79. The simulation is very simple, a rounded body is rolling and bouncing down on an inclined plane and I would like to process the motion data in another software.

Is it possible to export the position and orientation of the body in every frame?
I am a beginner assuming it would require an addon, but I could not find anything useful.

Edit:
Assume we have a local coordinate system attached to the body. I would like to export the position and orientation of the local system with respect to the global one. So a possible output would be a text file with 9 columns (x0,y0,z0 positions of the origin of the local system, and at least two direction vectors of the local x and y axes (of course the z axis can be computed later if needed)). The number of lines in the file would be the number of frames computed during the simulation.

Comment: do you mean tabulated X,Y,Z rotations, position and scale?

Comment: you can keyframe the animation - if you mean that. But as you can see - your question is not clear enough. If it would be - we wouldn't have to ask. So please improve your question.

Comment: It depends what kind of file format you need to export ...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question, I edited it and hope it provides the details you requested.

Comment: Some time ago I looked through the Python properties trying to find location and rotation of the physics engine controlled objects and was unsuccessful.

Comment: https://github.com/ProgrammingLanguageLeader/blender-csv-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. keyframe your animation

then use this script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] # of course you could get your object in better ways, i chose this to be quick ;)

for frame in range(1,30): # here you can also get your frame range in a better way...this is just a prototype, how it works, not how to show what's the best way
    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    print (frame, obj.location, obj.rotation_euler)
```

possible output:

1 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.7796)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
2 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.7702)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
3 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.7439)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
4 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.7005)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
5 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.6403)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
6 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.5631)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
7 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.4690)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
8 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.3580)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
9 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.2303)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
10 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0857)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
11 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.9243)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
12 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.7462)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
13 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.5514)> <Euler (x=-0.6051, y=-0.0003, z=-0.2745), order='XYZ'>
14 <Vector (-0.0019, -0.0023, 1.3683)> <Euler (x=-0.6003, y=0.0064, z=-0.2701), order='XYZ'>
15 <Vector (-0.0210, -0.0129, 1.3653)> <Euler (x=-0.5499, y=-0.0054, z=-0.2424), order='XYZ'>
16 <Vector (-0.0398, -0.0252, 1.3523)> <Euler (x=-0.4998, y=-0.0101, z=-0.2135), order='XYZ'>
17 <Vector (-0.0575, -0.0389, 1.3295)> <Euler (x=-0.4484, y=-0.0086, z=-0.1837), order='XYZ'>
18 <Vector (-0.0739, -0.0539, 1.2967)> <Euler (x=-0.3944, y=-0.0016, z=-0.1533), order='XYZ'>
19 <Vector (-0.0885, -0.0719, 1.2616)> <Euler (x=-0.3340, y=-0.0000, z=-0.1253), order='XYZ'>
20 <Vector (-0.1019, -0.0923, 1.2204)> <Euler (x=-0.2688, y=0.0000, z=-0.0984), order='XYZ'>
21 <Vector (-0.1143, -0.1144, 1.1706)> <Euler (x=-0.1986, y=0.0000, z=-0.0721), order='XYZ'>
22 <Vector (-0.1259, -0.1380, 1.1108)> <Euler (x=-0.1233, y=0.0000, z=-0.0466), order='XYZ'>
23 <Vector (-0.1366, -0.1629, 1.0403)> <Euler (x=-0.0429, y=-0.0000, z=-0.0216), order='XYZ'>
24 <Vector (-0.1433, -0.1856, 1.0063)> <Euler (x=0.0091, y=0.0072, z=-0.0071), order='XYZ'>
25 <Vector (-0.1443, -0.2039, 1.0366)> <Euler (x=0.0012, y=0.0141, z=-0.0068), order='XYZ'>
26 <Vector (-0.1453, -0.2221, 1.0498)> <Euler (x=-0.0066, y=0.0210, z=-0.0067), order='XYZ'>
27 <Vector (-0.1463, -0.2403, 1.0459)> <Euler (x=-0.0143, y=0.0278, z=-0.0065), order='XYZ'>
28 <Vector (-0.1471, -0.2568, 1.0321)> <Euler (x=-0.0095, y=0.0243, z=-0.0041), order='XYZ'>
29 <Vector (-0.1493, -0.2729, 1.0103)> <Euler (x=0.0003, y=0.0106, z=-0.0009), order='XYZ'>